# Laravel redirect to action with https

Tags: laravel-5

I am doing a redirect to a controller action in Laravel 5.8. The initial request is an https request, but the redirect for some reason creates an HTTP request. I don't quite understand why this happens. I know I can force HTTP to https, but I was hoping someone could help me understand why the redirect is an HTTP request.

```
            return redirect()->action('Auth\LoginController@loginAjax',['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'register_form' => true]);
```

Comment: probably because of your APP_URL .env variable... what do you have there? http or https? And I wouldn't recommend redirecting to action() use named routes and redirect like this `return redirect(route('route.name', $someVariable))`

Comment: My APP_URL is set to https, and I have the same problem if I redirect to a named route.

Comment: That's something really odd... you should debug it... what do you get when you make `dd(route('route.name'));` before that return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic Laravel redirect to a controller action or a named route, was always going to HTTP instead of https. To get around this, I did a full URL redirect, like this:

```
        return redirect()->to(env('APP_URL').'/login/ajax?email='.urlencode($request->email).'&password='.urlencode($request->password).'&register_form=true');
```

This solved the issue for me.